# Length of the dipole antenna

Tags: antenna, wave, dipole

I know it is really stupid question, but I can’t understand.

I have a picture with dipole antenna (different length). If I have the current distribution along the length, that it is easy to determine L, I mean number of lambda/2. But if I don’t have this distribution, how to determine?

[image]

In this case for example: why the first was determined as lambda/4?

[image]

Comment: Because it is physically 1/2 of a lambda/2 antenna. The other half is the reflected image in the ground plane.

Comment: The current is always zero at the free ends of the antenna because there's nowhere for it to flow to. You can work the rest out with some simple trigonometry.

Comment: @Chu what is difference between hd and lambda/2 dipole? difference that  in hd we have equal current distribution?

Answer (score 4):

Look at this gif file below showing the voltage and current distribution on a half wave dipole: -

[image]

Note that at the exact centre the voltage is zero no matter what current is flowing down the wires. In other words that point could be connected directly to ground rather like how you can lightly touch a string on a guitar in the middle and still play the same note but one octave higher (12th fret picture below): -

[image]

Next, think about the balanced voltage source driving the antenna and seperating the two wires with a very thin conducting plane (marked in green below): -

[image]

Now extend the green plane upwards and in all directions and you will find that the electric field it intersects is always zero. So you have a dipole split in half by a grounded plane and no change in performance.

Each wire to ground has an input resistance (at perfect tuning) of 37 ohms or 74 ohms net.The final step is just to throw one half away and drive with an unbalanced source into 37 ohms but you need a localized earth plane for it to work properly even with something like this: -

[image]

Comment: what is difference between hd and lambda/2 dipole? difference that  in hd we have equal current distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your comment. What is "hd"?

Comment: Hertzian dipole

Comment: hd= Hertzian dipole

Comment: one more quastion,  For Hertzian dipol we use TM-Mode?

Comment: I don't see any relevance in the hertzian dipole to your question: [The Hertzian dipole or Elementary doublet refers to a theoretical construction, rather than a physical antenna design: It is an idealized tiny segment of conductor carrying a RF current with constant amplitude and direction along its entire (short) length; a real antenna can be modeled as the combination of many Hertzian dipoles laid end-to-end.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Hertzian_dipole)